# PLSQL - delete root from tree data structure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables: Products and ProductGroups.

Deleting a root of hierarchy is allowed only if the later contains at most one subgroup. In that case, subgroup becomes a root of hierarchy. All products previously assigned to deleted root are assigned to new root of the hierarchy.

Deleting the last group that has assigned products is not allowed.

How can I implement this?

```
create or replace procedure pDeleteProductGroup(p_code VARCHAR2) IS
v_var "ProductGroups"."code"%type;
begin
select func_parent(p_code) into v_var
from "ProductGroups"
where "code"=p_code;

update "ProductGroups" 
set "parentCode"=v_var
where "code"=p_code;

update "Products" 
set "groupCode"=v_var
where "groupCode"=p_code;
end;

create or replace FUNCTION func_parent (p_groupCode VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  v_var "ProductGroups"."parentCode"%type;
  BEGIN
  select "parentCode" into v_var from "ProductGroups"
  where p_groupCode="code";

  if v_var is null
  then v_var:=null;

  end if;

  return v_var;

  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you don't have to do anything *special* but

- delete root node
- update the new root node's row and set its PARENT ID to NULL (as it is now the *root*, right)?

If that's not what you are asking, please, provide test case and explain what you'd want to do and which result you'd want to get.